# Using VBScript how can I check if the Spooler service is started and if not start it?

Tags: vbscript, service

I'd like to use VBScript to check if the Spooler service is started and if not start it, the code below checks the service status but I need some help modifying this so I can check if it is started.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Service")
For Each objService in colRunningServices 
    Wscript.Echo objService.DisplayName  & VbTab & objService.State
Next
```

Many thanks
Steven

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this. This command will start it if it isn't already running. No need to check in advance.

```
Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "NET START spooler", 1, false
```

Comment: certainly no need to shell out to call external commands. see my answer.

Comment: certainly no reason not to either. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("select State from Win32_Service where Name = 'Spooler'")

For Each objService in colRunningServices
    If objService.State <> "Running" Then
        errReturn = objService.StartService()
    End If
Next
```

Note you can also use `objService.started` to check if its started.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the completeless, here's an alternative variant using the [`Shell.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094.aspx) object:

```
Const strServiceName = "Spooler"

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
If Not oShell.IsServiceRunning(strServiceName) Then
  oShell.ServiceStart strServiceName, False
End If
```

Or simply:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.ServiceStart "Spooler", False    ''# This returns False if the service is already running
```